# Always redirected on 404 page with URL Rewrite and Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

So I download a clean copy of Codeigniter and replace the welcome controller and welcome_message view with (respectively) :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function test($number = 3)
    {
        echo $number;
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>pouet/lolmdr-2.html">LOLMDR</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my .htaccess file is :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^pouet/(.*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php/welcome/test/$2
```

I thought that when I clicked the link I would be redirected to my welcome/test function and then echoing 2. But instead I have a 404 page and I don't understand why.

Thanks

Comment: Usually the routing you're doing would be part of the config/routes.php file, and you'd rewrite: `RewriteRule (.*) index.php$1`.  Is there a particular reason you're doing the route matching in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**add this to you routes**

```
$route['test/(:num)'] = 'welcome/test/$1';
```

**then go to url:**

```
http://www.yoursite.com/test/3457
```

let us know the outcome dude

**welcome is your default controller, so :**

```
http://www.yoursite.com , will always = http://www.yoursite.com/welcome
```